# Word for "A Song that Sets a Scene in a Particular Region or Culture"

Tags: terminology, technical, music, cinema, theater

This is a technical term in theater and movie arts for a stereotyped piece of music that is played to cue the audience that a scene is set in a particular location.

E.g.

```
London --> Rule Britannia
Italy --> O sole Mio
German --> Oompah music
New York/Broadway --> No Business like Show business
```

Comment: "Riff"? e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_riff

Comment: This is perhaps an extended sense of 'leitmotif'.

Comment: I think the word I'm thinking of is a conceptual subset of `letimotif` but I think there is an even more specific term in the jargon. A `letimotif` can attach to characters or events, this attaches just to places.

Comment: @TechZen It's called Leitmotif

Answer (score 2):

*[Program music](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/program_music)* is “A form of art music that attempts to convey a scene, image, or mood”.

The [soundscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundscape)-related terms *keynote sounds* and *soundmark* also may be slightly relevant:

> ...keynote sounds may not always be heard consciously, but they "outline the character of the people living there" (Schafer).
>   A soundmark is a sound which is unique to an area

Comment: *Soundscape* is a different kind of animal. I suppose you've read the WP you cited.

Answer (score -1):

Signature tune or theme song; both are usually meant to identify a performer (Bing Crosby: "Where the Blue of the Night Meets the Gold of the Day) or a band (Glenn Miller: "Moonlight Serenade"; Jack Hylton: "She Shall Have Music"), but you also have this with regions and countries.

Comment: Why the downvote?